# While loop MIPS

Tags: while-loop, mips, roman-numerals

Looking to see if someone could tell me what is wrong with my while loop. I am trying to get the program to read the string entered by the user (Roman Numerals) and then compare to my if statements to in the end sum up the amount and print it out as an integer. right now it reads the first letter M (MXXI), but kicks out when it gets to X.

```
.data
buffer: .space 20
onlyCaps: .asciiz "Please enter only Capital Numbers\n"
enter1: .asciiz "Number out of range. Please enter another number\n"
enter2: .asciiz "Please enter your roman numeral: "
debug:  .asciiz "reach"
M:  .asciiz "1000"
D: .asciiz "500"
C: .asciiz "100"
L:  .asciiz "50"
X: .asciiz "10"
V:  .asciiz "5"
I: .asciiz "1"

.text

main:
la  $a0, onlyCaps   # "Enter Only Capital numbers"
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la  $a0, enter2     #prompt user with "Please enter a roman numeral:"
li  $v0, 4
syscall

la $a0, buffer      #load byte space into address
li $a1, 3           # allot the byte space for string

li $v0, 8           #read user input, j
syscall

li $t4, 1           #initialized at 1 for the loop

loop:
lb $t0, 0($a0)   # Save $v0 value to $t0
add $a0, $a0, $t4   #increment the address
j mCheck

#while loop ends here

mCheck:
beq $t0, 'M', mChar  # if $t0 equal M go to mChar
bne $t0, 'M', dCheck  # move to see if equals D

dCheck:
beq $t0, 'D', dChar  # if $t0 equal D go to dChar
bne $t0, 'D', cCheck

cCheck:
beq $t0, 'C', cChar  # if $t0 equal C go to cChar
bne $t0, 'C', lCheck

lCheck:
beq $t0, 'L', lChar  # if $t0 equal L go to lChar
bne $t0, 'L', xCheck

xCheck:
beq $t0, 'X', xChar  # if $t0 equal X go to xChar
bne $t0, 'X', vCheck

vCheck:
beq $t0, 'V', vChar  # if $t0 equal V go to vChar
bne $t0, 'V', iCheck

iCheck:
beq $t0, 'I', iChar  # if $t0 equal I go to iChar
bne $t0, 'I', error

mChar:   
la  $a0, M      #puts one hundred in $t3          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

dChar:   
la  $a0, D      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

cChar:   
la  $a0, C      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

lChar:   
la  $a0, L      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

xChar:   
la  $a0, X      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

vChar:   
la  $a0, V      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

iChar:   
la  $a0, I      # prints out 500          
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   loop

error:  
la  $a0, enter1     # Print error meg. then back to main
li  $v0, 4
syscall
j   done

done:   
li  $v0, 10         # Exit
syscall
```

Comment: There are some things in that code that make no sense. Why is there an `beqz $t4, done`? `$t4` is set to 1 before the loop and then never changed, so it will never be equal to zero. And what's with the `bne $t0, $t1, dCheck` and all the other such jumps? `$t1` hasn't been initialized anywhere in your code, and it's any case it's pointless to jump to the very next instruction since you'll end up there anyway.

Comment: @Michael i edited my code. thanks for the help. My question now is: I need a way for the while loop to stop running if there is not a character in the string left (ie MXXI_ -- at the _ spot). how could i do this?

Comment: The string that you read with syscall 8 will be null-terminated, so when you  find a byte with the value zero you've reached the end of the string.

Comment: So should i make an statement that says if $t0 is equal to 0 it should end? just want to make sure i understand your statement.